# pandas: using for loop to apply a function to all columns and append all smaller dfs together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to apply a function on a column that includes many dictionaries in each row.I am trying to convert the keys into columns and values into rows. for example, my data look like the following:

| id | dict_vals |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | {'key_a':[{'a':1,'b':8,'c':7},{'a':14,'b':6,'c':8},...}] |
| 345 | {'key_a':[{'a':5,'b':82,'c':72},{'a':4,'b':64,'c':81},...}] |

and I am trying to convert them to the following:

| id | a | b | c | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 8 | 7 | 14 | 6 | 8 |
| 345 | 5 | 82 | 72 | 4 | 64 | 81 |

so far, I have written my code like the following:

```
values = df.dict_values.str.replace("'", '"').apply(json.loads).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame(values)
df.dict_values = df.dict_values.apply(lambda x: x[:3])
dict_vals = df["dict_values"].apply(pd.Series)

# problem part
test_df = pd.DataFrame()
x = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1, 3):
    test_df2 = dict_vals[i].apply(pd.Series)
    x = pd.concat([test_df, test_df2])

print(x)
```

Inside the for loop, I am trying to convert each individual dictionary into a series (which gives me a dataframe that includes the a,b and c columns. Then, I want to concat all of these dataframes together. Unfortunately, when I print the x dataframe, it only shows me the table that includes data of the last dictionary, not all columns from all dictionaries. Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

thank you!

Comment: How was the first dataframe created . . . looks like something that could be handled using `pd.json_normalize(...)`

Comment: Difficult to answer unambiguously without a **reproducible** example, please provide the output of `df.to_dict()`